# Why is the main method in superclass executed by JVM?

Tags: java

When I execute:

```
 java B
```

for the following program, why does main of superclass A gets called? As I understand static methods belong to class level.

```
class A
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println("A.main");
    }
}

class B extends A{ }
```

Comment: Spoiler : yes they are

Comment: @Aaron I don't think this is a duplicate, It also has to with the start up with JVM.

Comment: @Tony you're right there's a little more to it, but it can easily be made clear in a comment : `java B` will call `B.main(String[] args)`, which is the static `main(String[] args)` inherited from `A`.

Comment: @Tony of course if you think there's more to it, feel free to vote to reopen the question, but I really think that the root of OP's misunderstanding was the false belief that static methods aren't inherited.

Comment: @Aaron But it is different with call `B.main`. JVM invoke it using a more complicated way, how could OP be sure they have same effect?

Comment: @Tony What's that more complicated way you're talking about? Do you mean what happens in `java B` versus a `B.main()` called from Java code? It sure is different, but the contract of `java B` is to call the static `main(String[] args)` of `B`. I'm not sure I understand your concern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Static methods are inherited by subclasses.